# Why doesn't a computation expression span the finally block

Tags: f#, f#-async

For example:

```
let test () = 
    async {
        try 
           do! someting ()
        finally
           do! sometingElse ()
    }
```

You can't do the `do!` in the finally you get the message from the compiler "you can only use do! in a computation expression" but it's still in there right.

I know how I can solve this but I would like to understand why the compiler restricts this scenario.

Ok after some fiddeling I think it's desugared like this: (I'm very happy we can write cexprs)

from:

```
async {
    try 
       do! someting ()
       do! sometingElse ()
    finally
       printfn "finally"
}
```

to:

```
async.TryFinally(
    async.Bind(
        someting(), (fun () -> 
            async.Bind(sometingElse (), (fun () -> 
                async.Zero())))), (fun () -> printfn "finally")) |> ignore
```

I get that the second part of the `TryFinally` doesn't support a `cexpr`.

Comment: As an exercise, to understand this behavior, try desugaring the workflow. You'll see how the resulting series of function calls makes this impossible.

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K: I'm not suggesting it's an impossible concept, only that the way workflows are presently desugared prevents it.

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K I would guess it is not so much an oversight as a decision to simplify the implementation in order to get the product out the door more quickly

Comment: Thanks guys, its clear it's not due to a limitation in the compiler or anything it's just not implemented. Does one of you want to officially answer this question and pick up the rep? :)

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K perhaps you should implement it then -- it is open source, after all :)

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K No need to apologize; it was just a suggestion, not a request.  Another possibility would be to see whether the topic has come up on https://fslang.uservoice.com/ and to raise it if it's not already there.

Comment: I think this can be implemented with an overload. C# did not support `finally` with asyncs in 5.x, because they thought it was not possible. Then they found a way and did it for 6.x. F# could go the same route and implement this for `task` or `async`, if it isn't already supported by adding an overloaded `TryFinally` on the CE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already discussed in the question, `try-finally` expressions with a computation expression for the `finally` clause are simply not supported (in F# 3.1).  However, it is easy to implement a function that has essentially such behavior.  Here is an example implementation:

```
let tryFinally (body: Async<'x>) (finalize: Async<unit>) : Async<'x> = async {
    let! result = Async.Catch body
    do! finalize
    return match result with
           | Choice1Of2 value -> value
           | Choice2Of2 exn -> raise exn
}
```

Comment: Awesome you even provided a solution :)

Comment: This won't call finalize when the body is pre-empted due to cancellation.

Comment: This will change the stacktrace of the original exception. I think using `ExceptionDispatchInfo` may help to prevent that. Here are some options of keeping the original stacktrace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202215/111575

Comment: Another option is to wrap it in an `IDispose`, which is directly supported by the CE.