# What is the preferred way of creating an adaptable generic return type when you don't care about the return value?

Tags: generics, f#

Suppose you want to create a function that has a final side effect (raises an error, exits the program, flies to the moon), what is the correct pattern to follow? I currently do it like this:

```
let fastExit x =
    match box x with
    | null ->
        System.Environment.FailFast("Something went terribly wrong, get out fast!")
        Unchecked.defaultof<_>  // adaptable generic return
    | _ -> x
```

I follow the above pattern pretty often (esp. in interaction with CLR's BCL) but never really wondered whether it is the F# way of doing things. Obviously, this only works if you either never return, or if you don't have to care about dangerous return values in pursuing code.

Note that, as a (now deleted) comment suggested, this also makes sense in composability and chainability (i.e., with the compose `>>` and pipe `|>` operators).

Comment: I would probably just put failwith to make the compiler happy

Comment: @JohnPalmer, you mean to put the `failwith` after whatever code needs to be executed (i.e., in this example after `FailFast`). That wouldn't work in some scenarios where you actually do not want to exit (though admittedly, that will be dangerous code).

Comment: That is probably what I would do

Comment: @JohnPalmer, in a way your suggestion makes sense, I guess. For instance `failwith "Unreachable code"`, in case you make a mistake at least you get a meaningful error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
let fastExit x =
    if isNull x then nullArg "x"
    elif otherGenericCheck x then failwith "x Didn't pass other generic check"
    // More generic checks
    x
```

Note that the compiler already constrains the type of `x` to have `null` as a value.

If you box it you will check any type, including those which use internally `null` as representation of 'valid' values, this means that if you pass an option type and its value is `None` it will fail.

So boxing or not depends on that.

Of course if the only check is the null check I wouldn't write this function at all, I think we both agree on that, unless there is a situation where you want to have the `T` effect, for instance when chaining many functions with `|>`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on boxing, but if I add `isNull`, which certainly has its uses, then I loose the genericity (as you mention in your answer). Furthermore I have situations with different signatures (i.e., `'a -> 'b` or `unit -> 'a` or whatever). But I think you're generally correct in that it is better to return from a function with `failwith` if you don't expect to ever reach that program point.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you said about the different signatures like ``unit->'a``. Could you please explain a bit more about that?

Comment: What I meant with `unit -> 'a` was, for instance, a function like `exit()`, which exits with a zero exit code. Or from [another q.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193629), the [`(ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture ex).Throw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.throw(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which is `unit -> unit`, but the containing function should have `unit -> 'a`, similar to the `reraise()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your example as:

```
let fastExit x = 
    if box x = null then // not the most efficient to way to check for null, but whatever
       System.Environment.FailFast("Oh noes!")
    x
```

This also works if you're calling the function for the exception it's going to throw. Not sure about functions that fly to the moon though...

That would be the general approach: you're writing imperative code, so write it in an imperative way.

Comment: Yes, this is another way of writing the example (and arguably a better way, but I often find myself avoiding `if-then`, must be my declarative-programming background). But I meant my question to be more generic, for instance, I also have signatures `unit -> 'a`, where I enforce `'a` with `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>`.

Comment: Well, in general what I suggest is to write it in such a way that you don't return in that code path, rather than return a meaningless or potentially dangerous value (like null) just to please the compiler. F# gives you tools to write imperative code, so if you're writing imperative logic, leverage them.